# Drop permission from a dbowner

Tags: sql-server, permissions

How can we remove the drop permission from a user or a role like `dbowner`? Want to restrict the `dbowner` from dropping the database.

Comment: Which database engine? MySQL, SQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you meant Sql Server and just mis-spelled db_owner, the answer holds true for any database: use the principle of least priviledge. That is, if an user shouldn't be able to drop the database, do not assign such privileges in the first hand at all.

Messing with built-in security group and role settings is bad practice, unless you are **very** sure what you are up to. Create new roles with appropriate settings instead. This way, you or any other DBA doesn't have to double-check if default permissions are really on default settings.

That being said, you might be able to prevent drops with some creative triggers. As how to do that, depends on your RDBMS.